# Is the quotient of a torsion-free module torsion-free?

Tags: group-rings, torsion-groups

Let $R=\mathbf{Z}[G]$, where $G$ is a finite group (not necessarily commutative). Suppose further that $M$ is an $R$-mod which is torsion-free. Can I say anything about the torsion elements of $M/R^n$ where $n\geq 1$? Is this torsion-free? If so, then why?

Comment: Well, it's not true in general that a quotient of a torsion free module is torsion free: any finite cyclic group (which is a $\mathbb Z$-module) has torsion and it the quotient of the torsion free and free $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I'm not sure about your particular case though...are you allowing $R^n$ to be any submodule that's isomorphic to $R^n$, or is there a "natural" submodule you had in mind?

Comment: Well I just wanted to quotient by any free module. I basically have an R-mod P/Free and wondering if this is torsion free as well. Clearly P and the free are torsion free, but I am a little stumped as to whether P/Free is torsion free.

Comment: Well, my counterexample above shows that it need not be free...

Comment: For example, if you let $G$ be the trivial group, then $R=\mathbb Z$, and my counterexample goes through.

Answer (score 0):

Original poster said in comments that “wanted to quotient by any free module”. Then the problem is already solved by @Nishant: the quotient is not necessarily torsion-free.

This follows from:

- The submodule *m* **Z** of **Z** is free 1-dimensional (if *m* ≠ 0), and **Z** / *m* **Z** has torsion iff |*m*| > 1;
- • In fact, *any* non-trivial torsion-free **Z**-module contains a 1-dimenional free submodule (isomorphic to **Z**), and likewise quotients with torsion;
- If *G* is trivial, then the group ring **Z**[*G*] is the same as **Z**.